# estou fazendo um trabalho em c para faculdade caso alguém possa ajudar

Tags: c, for, lógica

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz meu código normalmente, mas na hora de testar ele da certo para alguns e errado para outros, alem de variar a resposta dependendo do compilador caso  ache o erro ajudaria muito.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
  int n, i = 0, re, soma, k = 0;

  do {
    printf("informe quantos numeros tem na fileira: ");
    scanf("%d", & n);

    if (n <= 0 || n > 1000000) printf("valor invalido!\n\n informe outro:\n");

  } while (n < 0 || n > 1000000);

  int numeros[n];

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    do {
      printf("informe os numeros(de 1 a 1000): ");
      scanf("%d", & numeros[i]);

      if ((numeros[i] < 0 || numeros[i] > 1000)) printf("valor invalido!\n\n informe outro:\n");

    } while (numeros[i] < 0 || numeros[i] > 1000);

  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    soma = 0;

    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {

      soma = soma + numeros[i + k];

      if (soma % 8 == 0) {
        //printf("\n%d\n", soma);
        re++;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("\n\n%d", re);
}
```

Comment: Leia https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-cometi-ao-formular-minha-pergunta?cb=1   e veja se há algo que possa fazer para melhorar sua pergunta.

Comment: olá Vitor, já fez debug linha a linha para identificar o problema? O debug faz parte do aprendizado e ajuda a entender melhor como funciona o programa, sugiro fazer isso, ai provavelmente vai resolver ou chegar num ponto que não consegue, e vai ficar mais fácil pedir ajuda por exemplo "deu erro ou valor inválido na linha XXX no comando YYY" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não programo em C, mas resolvi testar seu código online, só fiz duas mudanças: a primeira, coloquei o valor inicial de `re` pra 0, assim como você fez com as variáveis `i` e `k`. Estava iniciando em 32000 e uns quebrado.

A segunda modificação foi no loop `k`, cujo o valor inicial eu alterei pra `i`, ficando assim:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    soma = 0;

    for (k = i; k < n; k++) {
        soma = soma + numeros[k];

        if (soma % 8 == 0) {
            re++;
        }
    }
}
```

O motivo dessa alteração é que o primeiro loop determina o valor inicial do retângulo e o segundo, o final dele. Na verdade, começando o segundo loop no índice 0, você vai estar repetindo cálculo que você já fez.

Antes

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo `i = 0` e `k = 1`, ele irá somar `3 + 4`. Se `i = 1` e `k = 0`, ele vai somar de novo 3 + 4.

Testei esses exemplos aí em dois sites e deram ok (não tenho compilador instalado).

Aqui: https://onlinegdb.com/YjZpwUPyD

Comment: "deram ok"  quer dizer que encontrou mesmo 3 soluções para 3 4 6 0 2 9? Quais seriam? Não consigo ver essa solução

Comment: @arfneto Sim, encontrou os 3. No enunciado só diz pra retornar apenas a **quantidade** de soluções. Todavia, segue o código alterado que mostra as soluções também: https://onlinegdb.com/KpUIPjAKi

Comment: Encontrou QUAIS 3? Até escrevi um programa, mas não consigo ver as 3 soluções para esses números.  E meu programa também não. Que solução seu programa achou?

Comment: @arfneto não viu o código do link que postei no comentário anterior? Enfim, segue os resultados: `3 + 4 + 6 + 0 + 2 + 9`, `6 + 0 + 2` e `0`.

Comment: entendo. Não, não tinha visto. Nunca vejo links a partir de comentários. Obrigado.  Não considerei 0 como solução. _my bad_

Comment: corrigi meu exemplo. ! Obrigado

Comment: valeu,  de certo, ajudou muito!

Answer (score 2):

Em relação ao exemplo com 3 4 6 0 2 9 está claro que 6 0 2 somam 8 e está ok, a soma de todos os números dá 24 então esta é a segunda solução.
Uma terceira solução é o 0 por si só, como seria o caso de qualquer múltiplo de 8 num quadrado. (@Kiritonito me apontou isso)

#### Uma notação geral

Uma solução possível pode ser escrita como um par `(i,j)` com o início em `i` e o comprimento `j` da sequência.

Para `8 0 8 0 8` temos

```
0, 1    0, 2    0, 3    0, 4    0, 5
1, 1    1, 2    1, 3    1, 4    2, 1
2, 2    2, 3    3, 1    3, 2    4, 1
```

As `15` soluções.

#### Caso particular

- Com todos os quadrados com multiplos de 8 o total de soluções deve ser `(N+1)*N / 2`, e 10 quadrados com 8 devem levar a 55 soluções

#### Um exemplo em C

Alterei um pouco o programa original para gravar em arquivo **q8.txt** as soluções encontradas, assim se pode conferir o programa e ver os "quadrados"  encontrados.

```
#define LIMITE_ (1000 * 1000)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char* s_padrao = "q8.txt"; // entrada padrao
    unsigned    limite = LIMITE_; // limite padrao
    char        arquivo_s[80];
    char        na_tela = 0;
    char linha[256];
    if (argc > 1) 
        strcpy(arquivo_s, argv[1]);
    else
        strcpy(arquivo_s, s_padrao);
    //fprintf(stderr, "Saida em \"%s\"\n", arquivo_s);

    FILE* S = fopen(arquivo_s, "a");
    if (S == 0) return -1; // nao abriu saida

    unsigned    N;
    int         res = scanf("%d", &N);
    fgets(linha, 256, stdin); // le o resto da linha
    if (res != 1) return -2;
    if (N > LIMITE_) N = LIMITE_;
    fprintf(S,"%d numeros\n", N);
    short* V = (short*)malloc(sizeof(short) * N);
    if (V == NULL) return -3;

    // le os numeros ate preencher o vetor inicial
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        res = scanf("%hd", (V+i) );
        if (res != 1)
            return -4;
        else
            fprintf(S, "%6d", *(V + i));
    }
    fprintf(S, "\n");

    // busca as solucoes
    unsigned total = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        if (*(V+i) % 8 == 0)
        {
            fprintf(S, "%d, 1\n", i);
            total += 1;
        }
        unsigned soma = *(V+i); // o primeiro, claro
        for (unsigned j = i+1; j < N; j += 1)
        {
            soma += *(V + j);
            if ((soma % 8) == 0)
            {
                fprintf(S, "%d, %d\n", i, 1+j-i);
                total += 1;
            };
        }
    }
    fprintf(S, "Total: %d solucoes\n\n", total);
    fclose(S);
    printf("%d\n", total);
    free(V);
    return 0;
};  // main()
```

#### Saída em *q8.txt* (exemplos)

Esse é o arquivo gerado

```
6 numeros
     3     4     6     0     2     9
0, 6
2, 3
3, 1
Total: 3 solucoes

7 numeros
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
Total: 0 solucoes

5 numeros
     8     0     8     0     8
0, 1
0, 2
0, 3
0, 4
0, 5
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
2, 1
2, 2
2, 3
3, 1
3, 2
4, 1
Total: 15 solucoes


4 numeros
     0     0     0     0
0, 1
0, 2
0, 3
0, 4
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
2, 1
2, 2
3, 1
Total: 10 solucoes

4 numeros
     8    16    24    32
0, 1
0, 2
0, 3
0, 4
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
2, 1
2, 2
3, 1
Total: 10 solucoes
```

#### saida no terminal

```
6
3 4 6 0 2 9
3

7
1 1 1 1
1 1 1
0

5
8 0 8 0 8
15
```

#### De volta ao programa original

```
  if (n <= 0 || n > 1000000) printf("valor invalido!\n\n informe outro:\n");

  } while (n < 0 || n > 1000000);

  int numeros[n];

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    do {
      printf("informe os numeros(de 1 a 1000): ");
      scanf("%d", & numeros[i]);

      if ((numeros[i] < 0 || numeros[i] > 1000)) printf("valor invalido!\n\n informe outro:\n");

    } while (numeros[i] < 0 || numeros[i] > 1000);`
```

Sugestões

- declare variáveis de controle do `for` no próprio comando
- ao usar `do/while` evite construções como essa em que testa duas vezes a mesma coisa
- `main()` retorna int.
- declare vetores de dimensão constante ou use **malloc()** e crie o vetor na hora.